# How to enable HTTP2 in Cloud Foundry using nginx-buildpack?

Tags: nginx, http2, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to enable HTTP2 in cloud foundry using NGINX buildpack or any? I understand that GoRouter will not support HTTP2 but not sure if there is any workaround for this?

My original requirement is to serve large JS file from Cloud Foundry so to improve performance looking for enabling HTTP2.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same question, but the solution here applies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55552398/1585136.

> 1. If you have the need for public clients (i.e.clients outside CF) to connect to your app, you need to use TCP routing. If your provider doesn't enable this by default, find another provider (see this list of public providers, hint Pivotal Web Services will provide TCP routes upon request) or self host.
> 2. If you only need to use HTTP/2 and/or gRPC between apps running on CF, you can use the container to container network. When you talk app to app, there are no restrictions (so long as you properly open required ports). You can use TCP, UDP and any protocol built on top of those. There some details about how this works here.

You'll also need the Nginx http_v2_module. This is a [very recent addition](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/buildpacks-ci/pull/66) and isn't yet in a build of the Nginx or Staticfile buildpack as I write this. It's should be, if everything goes right, in the next release though. That should be Nginx buildpack 1.1.10+ and Staticfile buildpack 1.5.8+.

> My original requirement is to serve large JS file from Cloud Foundry so to improve performance looking for enabling HTTP2.

It might, it might not. Your mileage may vary. HTTP/2 isn't a silver bullet. This explains this well.

https://www.nginx.com/blog/http2-module-nginx/